# Cant install libgazebo8-dev header

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I was following the gazebo tutorials (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_i&tut=guided_i5) and needed to install the libgazebo8-dev header files. Everytime I run the command I get an error of "Unable to locate package libgazebo8-dev".

I then looked up the packages list of Ubuntu and on searching for it couldn't find it there too.
Google search for the header didn't help me either.

I guess the libgazebo8-dev has been removed from the Ubuntu library.

Can anyone help me with this? Or provide a link to download the library?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19625/cant-install-libgazebo8-dev-header/) by [harrykarwasra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5512/harrykarwasra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is not an official Ubuntu package, you need to add OSRF's packages first, [like this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1